# Pandas pivot_table: Defining Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I'm new to pandas and python in general. I'm pulling data from an Access database and creating a pivot table.

```
PTable = TRep.pivot_table(values = ['Students'],
                  index = ['GradeLevel', 'Class'],
                  columns = ['Grade'], 
                  aggfunc='count', fill_value=0, margins=True, dropna=True, 
                  margins_name='Grand Total')
```

`Grade` will always be `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F` - And I want the resulting pivot table to always show columns for those 5 grades even if there are 0 students with that grade.

Currently, if the list of students pulled from Access does not contain a student receiving a `C` (for example), the resulting pivot table will have the `C` column omitted.

Is there a way to define constant columns in a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have tried:

This is my sample data:

```
   GradeLevel   Class   Student     Grade
0     I           1       AAA         A
1     I           2       BBB         B
2     I           2       CCC         D
3     I           3       DDD         E
4     I           4       EEE         A
5     II          1       FFF         B
6     II          2       GGG         A
7     II          3       HHH         B
8     II          4       KKK         D
9     II          1       LLL         D
10    II          2       MMM         E
11    III         1       NNN         E
12    III         2       OOO         A
13    III         2       PPP         A
14    III         3       QQQ         A
```

Change ***Grade*** column to ***category***.

```
df["Grade"] = df["Grade"].astype('category')
```

Set the level of category of ***Grade*** column.

```
df["Grade"] = df["Grade"].cat.set_categories(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
```

Pivot the data:

```
df.pivot_table(values = ["Student"], index = ["GradeLevel", "Class"], 
               columns = ["Grade"], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0, 
               margins=True, dropna=False, margins_name='Grand Total')
```

Result:

```
        Student
    Grade            A  B   C   D   E   Grand Total
GradeLevel  Class                       
    I         1      1  0   0   0   0   1.0
              2      0  1   0   1   0   2.0
              3      0  0   0   0   1   1.0
              4      1  0   0   0   0   1.0
    II        1      0  1   0   1   0   2.0
              2      1  0   0   0   1   2.0
              3      0  1   0   0   0   1.0
              4      0  0   0   1   0   1.0
    III       1      0  0   0   0   1   1.0
              2      2  0   0   0   0   2.0
              3      1  0   0   0   0   1.0
              4      0  0   0   0   0   NaN
Grand Total          6  3   0   3   3   15.0
```

But from the pivot table we still see the ***NaN*** value. So to remove that ***NaN*** value:

```
(df.pivot_table(values = ["Student"], index = ["GradeLevel", "Class"], 
               columns = ["Grade"], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0, 
               margins=True, dropna=False, margins_name='Grand Total')).dropna()
```

Result:

```
        Student
    Grade             A     B   C   D   E   Grand Total
GradeLevel  Class                       
     I        1       1     0   0   0   0   1.0
              2       0     1   0   1   0   2.0
              3       0     0   0   0   1   1.0
              4       1     0   0   0   0   1.0
     II       1       0     1   0   1   0   2.0
              2       1     0   0   0   1   2.0
              3       0     1   0   0   0   1.0
              4       0     0   0   1   0   1.0
     III      1       0     0   0   0   1   1.0
              2       2     0   0   0   0   2.0
              3       1     0   0   0   0   1.0
Grand Total           6     3   0   3   3   15.0
```

Hope it is useful...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can always put some 'touch-up' onto the df once it's been created. For example, you can add a column and fill it up with nan i.e. `df['C'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the grades column to categorical, specifying all possible values.

```
TRep[‘Grade’] = pd.Categorical(TRep[‘Grade’], [‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, ‘F’])
```

Then pass `dropna=False` to `pivot_table` and it’ll include all the columns.

Comment: This works and shows all of the columns that I want, but now with dropna=False I'm getting extra rows without any useful info. Is there a way to dropna=True for index and dropna=False for rows?